# JSON string too large

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm using a [jQuery plugin](http://tomcoote.co.uk/wp-content/CodeBank/Demos/JSONSuggestBox/demo.html) that uses a JSON string to suggest its data.

Everything works fine if the JSON string has less than X elements. Above this limit nothing happens, autosuggest fails. I guess it's because there's a kind of parsing limit, but how can I bypass this please ? I have an array of +5000 elements...

Here is my json code :

```
var SearchTxt = '[{"t":"word one"},{"t":"word two"}, ...]';
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally found the source of this problem. There were a parsing error due to the simple quotes... Don't ask me why it only started to happen with a certain number of elements while all quotes where already escaped.

Well, so I changed this :

```
var SearchTxt = '[{"t":"word one"},{"t":"word two"}, ...]';
```

to

```
var SearchTxt = [{"t":"word one"},{"t":"word two"}, ...];
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

[`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is using the `GET` method, which is [limited by a varying length for each browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/812962/913097). So in your case the returned result apparently exceeds that limit. What you want to do is change

```
$.getJSON(settings.url,{search:text},function(data){if(data){buildResults(data,text);}
else{$(results).html('').hide();}});
```

in the source code of the plugin into

```
$.post(settings.url,{search:text},function(data){if(data){buildResults(data,text);}
else{$(results).html('').hide();}},'json');
```

which will make it do a `POST` request instead. Also, make sure to change the reference(s) to the global `$_GET` array into `$_POST` if any, in your server-side script.

Comment: thanks inha, but I'm really new to json, and I don't know where to fix this in the [plugin code](http://tomcoote.co.uk/wp-content/CodeBank/Demos/JSONSuggestBox/jquery.jsonSuggest-dev.js). I tried several things but nothing works.

Comment: You can use CTRL+F to find somehing in an open document and CTRL+V to paste something you have already copied.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "parsing limit" with JSON, any limitation is set by the server parsing the JSON request.

Comment: ok, but how can I check this parameter and how to fix this ? 
My array works with 2000-2500 elements, but I need to add the double

Comment: change max_post_size in php.ini to change the maximum post size